# BeautifulSoup find_all() Doesn't Find All Requested Elements

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am seeing some strange behavior with BeautifulSoup as demonstrated in the example below.

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """<p style='color: red;'>This has a <b>color</b> of red. Because it likes the color red</p>
<p class='blue'>This paragraph has a color of blue.</p>
<p>This paragraph does not have a color.</p>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
pattern = re.compile('color', flags=re.UNICODE+re.IGNORECASE)
paras = soup.find_all('p', string=pattern)
print(len(paras)) # expected to find 3 paragraphs with word "color" in it
  2
print(paras[0].prettify())
  <p class="blue">
    This paragraph as a color of blue.
  </p>

print(paras[1].prettify())
  <p>
    This paragraph does not have a color.
  </p>
```

As you can see for some reason the first paragraph of `<p style='color: red;'>This has a <b>color</b> of red. Because it likes the color red</p>` is not being picked up by `find_all(...)` and I cannot figure out why not.

Answer (score 2):

The `string` property expects the tag to contain only text and not tags. If you try printing `.string` for the first `p` tag, it'll return `None`, since, it has tags in it.

Or, to explain it better, the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string) says:

> If a tag has only one child, and that child is a `NavigableString`, the child is made available as `.string`
>
> If a tag contains more than one thing, then it’s not clear what `.string` should refer to, so `.string` is defined to be `None`

The way to overcome this, is to use a `lambda` function.

```
html = """<p style='color: red;'>This has a <b>color</b> of red. Because it likes the color red</p>
<p class='blue'>This paragraph has a color of blue.</p>
<p>This paragraph does not have a color.</p>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

first_p = soup.find('p')
print(first_p)
# <p style="color: red;">This has a <b>color</b> of red. Because it likes the color red</p>
print(first_p.string)
# None
print(first_p.text)
# This has a color of red. Because it likes the color red

paras = soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == 'p' and 'color' in tag.text.lower())
print(paras)
# [<p style="color: red;">This has a <b>color</b> of red. Because it likes the color red</p>, <p class="blue">This paragraph has a color of blue.</p>, <p>This paragraph does not have a color.</p>]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to grap the `'p'` you can just do:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """<p style='color: red;'>This has a <b>color</b> of red. Because it likes the color red</p>
<p class='blue'>This paragraph has a color of blue.</p>
<p>This paragraph does not have a color.</p>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

paras = soup.find_all('p')
for p in paras:
  print (p.get_text())
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually figured out why specifying the string (or text for older versions of BeautifulSoup) parameter of `find_all(...)` doesn't give me what I want but, the following does give me a generalized solution.

```
pattern = re.compile('color', flags=re.UNICODE+re.IGNORECASE)
desired_tags = [tag for tag in soup.find_all('p') if pattern.search(tag.text) is not None]
```

Comment: I've explained why this is happening in the answer above. What you've done as a list comprehension can be done using `lambda` too.